# Collecting times of day from users in several different time zones

Tags: javascript, html, datetime, timezone, locale

I have an app with many users, and I'd like to ask users to each select a time of day that they'd like to have a meeting (in some sense) so that we can pick the time for which the most users are available.

The users are in different time zones. I'd like to build an HTML5/Javascript interface that can collect such times of day in a straightforward way and aggregate them together, taking into account the time differences, so that I can collect the data in a way that makes it easy to see the best time to get everyone together?

Please take into account the following:

- I'd like to use supported HTML5 form fields and semantic tags where available, instead of doing a lot of secondary computations in Javascript.
- I'd like to display time selections in the user's current timezone, but store the data in some normalized way to compare across time zones.

I have a feeling that the Javascript Date `toLocale...` functions will be helpful here, but still don't see a very straightforward way to do this. Elegant solutions appreciated.

Comment: This is quite a broad question.  Could you focus it please?

Comment: @MattJohnson thought it would be easier just to post the code that I used.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, it turned out that [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is perfect for this problem.

For example, I can generate a list of moments at a fixed time with respect to UTC:

```
# Default time selections: 9AM EST to 11PM EST
m = moment.utc(hours: 9 + 5).local()
return (m.clone().add('hours', x) for x in [0..14])
```

Then, I can display these times in the user's timezone while storing the results in a fixed timezone (using handlebars, for example):

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select a time</option>    
{{#each momentList}}
    <option value="{{valueFormatted}}">{{displayFormatted}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

where the respective helpers are

```
# Store all values in GMT-5
Template.tsTimeOptions.valueFormatted = -> @zone(300).format('HH ZZ')

# Display values in user's timezone
Template.tsTimeOptions.displayFormatted = -> @local().format('hA [UTC]Z')
```

This generates HTML like the following:

```
<select name="pickTime1" class="input-medium" required="">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select a time</option>    
    <option value="09 -0500">6AM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="10 -0500">7AM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="11 -0500">8AM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="12 -0500">9AM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="13 -0500">10AM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="14 -0500">11AM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="15 -0500">12PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="16 -0500">1PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="17 -0500">2PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="18 -0500">3PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="19 -0500">4PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="20 -0500">5PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="21 -0500">6PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="22 -0500">7PM UTC-08:00</option>    
    <option value="23 -0500">8PM UTC-08:00</option>
</select>
```

This achieves the goal of asking users for times in their timezone while storing all of the results in a common format that can be aggregated over.